# Datetime to Integer

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have one problem... There is a table in my MySQL database that stores to-do list entries inside a JQuery-type calendar.
I had to generate a `calendar_id` that will generate a reminder once I created timestamp (considered as time I clicked on any of the calender dateboxes, to key in some  to-do tasks - put it simple: created datetime).

This to-do list activities app is an external application that I've been working on to integrate with my own management system. I noticed that,the timestamp column is in `int(11)` format, so whatever timestamp entered will be converted into integer.

For example, take a look at this:

```
2012-02-22 15:31:24
```

converted to

```
1329899400
```

How can we convert datetime to this format? It's not in seconds when I tried:

```
intval(floor($datetime/86400));
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't believe DateTime cannot be represented by an Integer.  DateTime is the number of seconds since ( depending on several favtors ) since a specfic date in 1970.  Your going to have to figure out what the value represents, since it really doesn't seem, like you actually know.

Comment: Yes, I'm figuring out what the value represents because the number sequence is kinda 'odd' for any inserted timestamp..At least for me, this is my first time I experience this as I'm still learning PHP/MySQL :)

Comment: @Selang: The number is a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp). They are widely used (obviously especially on UNIX systems).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`FROM UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) can format UNIX timestamps into datetime fields:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time)
FROM ...
```

The reverse function would be [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

---

Alternatively you can do it in PHP, if available:
To store a date into the DB format it like this:

```
$datetimeStr = '2012-02-22 15:31:24';
$datetime = strtotime($datetimeStr);
```

To retrieve it from the DB and format it to the original format, use something like this:

```
$dateTimeFromDB = '1329921084';
$datetimeStr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTimeFromDB);
```

Comment: Geez, I'm totally a fool for not learning this Unixtime function...thanks for replying

Comment: What about dates smaller than 01.01.1970?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function for you

Comment: Is "INSERT INTO db.table (`timestamp`) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP($datetime))"; the right command in my case?

Comment: If your `$datetime` is in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format (note that you can use different separators instead of `-` and `:`, then yes. Alternatiely, seeing that you use PHP, you can use it's `strtotime()` function.

Comment: I forgot to tell you,I did performed $datetime = strtotime($datetime); but the values in the database will only read 2012, which is the 'Year' part.. How that happened?